Is there a way to do scoped type variables in zig for a generic struct?
I'm pulling from Haskell to look into this question, but allow me to expose the zig example first.
I'd like to instantiate a type like the following:
const GenericType = struct {
    aType: type,
    aFun: (fn (v: aType) aType),
};

I shall explain it as well to hedge against my current lack of zig knowledge. In short, I want to make a type that contains a type aType and a function that maps that type into itself like a unary operator aFun :: aType -> aType in Haskell lingo. Naturally, I'm aware that those types should be compile-time determined, but am unaware of how to inform the compiler that aType should be unified within the struct.
What I'm trying to do is functionally equivalent to the following Haskell code:
data GenericType a = GenericType
  {aFun :: a -> a}

genInstance :: GenericType Int
genInstance = GenericType (\int -> int + 1)

Maybe this is repetitive, but I'm wondering if it's possible to reference that type (in the haskell example, simply named a) in zig similar to how it's done in Haskell, directly on the type structure. What I mean by that is I know it is possible to accomplish the same goal with a zig function by either only receiving a function type
fn functionParam(comptime aType: type, arg: aType, func: (fn (aType) aType)) aType {
    // this compiles just fine and this scope contains 
    // aType and func with types unified
    func(arg);
}

or even returning a struct from the function to have the type available later
// line breaks on function's args and return types to improve readability
fn GenericType (comptime aType: type, func: (fn (aType) aType)) // args types
               (struct { aType: type, 
                         aFun: (fn (aType) aType) })            // return type
{
    return .{
        .aType = aType,
        .aFun = func,
    };
}

but even here the types aren't actually unified: in the above, I'd like to enforce that aType from the returning struct is the same aType from the first parameter

I think the way you've set things up as a function works well already. The compiler will enforce that you cannot mutate your copy of the returned struct from fn GenericType so they're guaranteed to be unified so long as you know that GenericType is the producer of the value.

But if you're primary concern is with consuming the structure instances, you can always use comptime to enforce the equality of the types.

Zig also doesn't have anything like interfaces that would allow you to group types based on functionality, so you necessarily have to resort to compile-time ducktyping.
